# Why both UNICODE and _UNICODE?

Tags: visual-c++, unicode

I've been looking at the command line generated by Visual Studio, and for one of my project it defines two symbols: `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE`.  Now if I understand this document [this rather old](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194799.aspx)  document, the `_UNICODE` symbol is a VC++ thing that causes certain standard functions to use `wchar_t` instead of `char` in their interfaces.

But what does the `UNICODE` without an underscore mean?

Comment: Maybe use functions like CreateWindowW instead of CreateWindowA when UNICODE defined, so UNICODE is for WinApi, _UNICODE is for C run time library

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Raymond Chen explains it here: [TEXT vs. _TEXT vs. _T, and UNICODE vs. _UNICODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643):

> The plain versions without the underscore affect the character set the Windows header files treat as default. So if you define `UNICODE`, then `GetWindowText` will map to `GetWindowTextW` instead of `GetWindowTextA`, for example. Similarly, the `TEXT` macro will map to `L"..."` instead of `"..."`.
>
> The versions with the underscore affect the character set the C runtime header files treat as default. So if you define `_UNICODE`, then `_tcslen` will map to `wcslen` instead of `strlen`, for example. Similarly, the `_TEXT` macro will map to `L"..."` instead of `"..."`.

Looking into Windows SDK you will find things like this:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 33):

In a nutshell,

`UNICODE` is used by Windows headers,

whereas

`_UNICODE` is used by C-runtime/MFC headers.

Answer (score 22):

Compiler vendors have to prefix the identifiers in their header files with an underscore to prevent them from colliding with your identifiers.  So `<tchar.h>`, a compiler header file, uses _UNICODE.  The Windows SDK header files are compiler agnostic, and stone-cold old, it uses UNICODE without the underscore.  You'll have to define both.