# c++ identifier "Luservar" is undefined

Tags: c++

I am writing a little app that uses SMTP.

And I got a weird error:

```
identifier "Luservar" is undefined`
```

code:

```
o_smtp->BodyText = _T(uservar->get_h().c_str() + ":" + pass_str.c_str() + "\n" + get_mac().c_str());
```

Why is it saying `Luservar` if i say `uservar`?

I have tried:

```
o_smtp->BodyText = uservar->get_h().c_str() + ":" + pass_str.c_str() + "\n" + get_mac().c_str();
```

But then I get a error like this:
`expression must have integral or unscoped enum type`

I am fairly new to C++ and maybe its the wrong way to merge strings?

Comment: Please post your compiler command-line options.

Comment: `c_str()` usually returns a `const char*` - you cannot merge those with other `const char*` "strings" using `+`

Comment: @Dai how do i check it in visual studio?

Comment: @UnholySheep how would I do it?

Comment: `_T` can only be applied to `"literals"` - Applying it to arbitrary expressions is not going to work

Comment: You shouldn't be using `_T` anyway. It's 2020 - use UTF-8 everywhere! (Or at least use `wchar_t` with UTF-16 consistently in your code for Win32). `_T` is to allow you to recompile for the (obsolete, horrible, ill-advised, and demonic) MBCS vs. ANSI vs. "Unicode" world we had in the late-1990s. It's completely wrong to use it today.

Comment: What SMTP library are you using? What is the type of `o_smtp` and `o_smtp->BodyText`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **DO NOT USE `_T` or `TEXT()`. Yegods.**

  - These are positively ancient and obsolete macros that Microsoft absolutely needs to remove from `Windows.h` (and they should have removed them *decades* ago).

    - Even Raymond Chen, everyone's favourite Win32-centric blogger, [doesn't know why `_T` exists](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=40643)!
  - [Just make sure `#define UNICODE` is enabled in your project properties and forget about the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953025/why-both-unicode-and-unicode).
- If you're writing C++ (with classes and objects, and using types from the STL and C++'s standard library), then you shouldn't be writing C (by using typedefs, structs and raw pointers).

  - Remember that C++ and C are different languages despite their syntactic similarities and C++'s heritage in C.
  - Fun fact: Microsoft's VisualC++ is not a C compiler - it only supports the parts of C needed to compile C++: [Does Visual Studio 2017 fully support C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615184/does-visual-studio-2017-fully-support-c99)
  - What I mean by this is that if you're using `std::string` then you should not use `.c_str()` unless you really have to - and in this case, you don't have to (well, not for string-concatenation at least).

As for your code...

- I assume these variables and function return-values are typed as `std::string`:

  - `uservar->get_h()`
  - `pass_str`
  - `get_mac()`
- I assume that `o_smtp->BodyText` is typed as `char*`.
- I assume that you simply want a concatenate those strings together, along with the literals in your C++ code.

  - In which case, let `std::string` do the concatenation for you!

```
std::string bodyText = uservar->get_h() + ":" + pass_str + "\n" + get_mac();

o_smtp->BodyText = bodyText.c_str();
```

**However** you need to be careful about the lifetime of `std::string bodyText` - as soon as `bodyText` leaves scope then its `c_str` expires. See this thread: [What is std::string::c_str() lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime)

Remember that `bodyText.c_str()` provides a `char*` **view** of `bodyText` (i.e. it's a different representation of the same chunk of memory), rather than a copy of clone or `bodyText`, so if `o_smtp->BodyText` is long-life'd then you'll need to ensure `bodyText` has the same lifetime as `o_smtp` or copy `bodyText`'s character buffer to a separate buffer that will live long enough - or determine if `o_smtp` will take ownership of its `BodyText` character buffer.