# wout printing address of wide character

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, outputstream, wchar-t, gn

I am calling a function which outputs a wide character in the output stream. Consider:-

```
wcout<<GetOutput();
```

and the definition of function is like this:-

```
const wchar_t* GetOutput()
{
        std::wstringstream stringStream;
        stringStream << out_name << " " << out_type << out_subtype;
        wchar_t* check = new wchar_t[stringStream.str().length() + 1];
        wcscpy(check, stringStream.str().c_str());
        return check;
}
```

Now, when this functions is called on cmd, it is giving me correct output. But, when the same function is called on linux(WSL), I am getting output as an address which is something like this:-

```
0x1ef110ad0
```

Why is this happening?

Edit:-
The definition of variables are as follows:-

```
const std::wstring out_name = L"My Name";
const std::wstring out_type = L"Type1";
const std::wstring out_subtype = L"SubType1";
```

Comment: What is `out_name`? What is `out_type`? What is `out_subtype`? Why do you use the narrow-character string `" "` for the space?

Comment: @Rohit Nagpal what does wprintf gives you?

Comment: What is `wout`? Do you mean `std::wcout`? You also have memory leaks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude out_name and other variables are just wstring which are assigned value.

Comment: @vish wprintf doesn't output anything in linux but in windows it works.

Comment: @MirceaIspas Sorry, it was a typo. Edited it. wcout and std::wcout both didn't worked.

Comment: What happens if you change the narrow-character string `" "` to the wide-character string `L" "`? Or the wide character `L' '`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now, I am getting garbage value.

Comment: What is the contents of your variables? And please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also, why do you return a pointer from `GetOutput`? Why not a `std::wstring` object?

Comment: @RohitNagpal could you check what charset you are using? If MBCS, I think it **may** make sense that it would print address.

Comment: @vish After removing MBCS and inserting _UNICODE, address is not getting printed, but the thing is output now contains garbage value.

Comment: @RohitNagpal good to know. Do note, you need to define both `_UNICODE` & `UNICODE`. Give it a try and let us know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953025/why-both-unicode-and-unicode#:~:text=_UNICODE%3A,of%20%22...%22%20.

Comment: @vish I am using both in my character set, but still having issues.

Comment: @RohitNagpal okay, could you tell us what are types and content of `out_name , out_type, out_subtype`?

Comment: @vish I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: @RohitNagpal If I understand correctly, this would be printing on remote machine on linux terminal right? In any case, if this is a big application, I would ask you to make a tiny one with `main`, `GetOutput`, with minimum headers, test it. If you get same results post it along with information about whether you are using DEBUG or RELEASE, Processor configuration, x86, x64, ARM, ARM64. I would think your best bet though is change one thing a time. Also make sure to run that app without VS remote debugging on that machine.

Comment: @vish Thanks for the advice buddy. I will try that.